# itemController for hasMany

Tags: ember.js

I've been struggling with the following question for a while: How do I assign an itemController to child elements in a hasMany relationship?

My use case is the following: I have an Ember.View (ProjectView) in which I manipulate areas on the map using the Google Maps API. I have a model for the Area and the Project model "hasMany" areas.

I do not have any save buttons or the like in my app, but rather sync changes  to the backend when a change occurs (using a debounce function). In order to avoid nasty inFlight errors, I am using a modified version of the Ember.AutoSaving plugin https://github.com/gaslight/ember-autosaving, which buffers my changes and synchronizes them with the model when it's ready. However, in order to use this, I need to apply an itemController using this Mixin to every Area in my hasMany relation. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

The Handlebars `{{each}}` helper has an `itemController` option. When this option is specified each object will be wrapped by a controller instance. So something like this should work:

```
//from your project template
{{#each area in areas itemController="area"}}
  <pre>
    area is an AreaController: {{area}}
    area.content is a reference to the model: {{area.content}}
{{/each}}
```

See the [handlebars {{each}} API docs] (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each) for more details

**EDIT: Option 2**

As an alternative to using the `{{each}}` helper, use an `ArrayController` to represent the collection and set it's `itemController` property. For example:

```
App.AreasController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'area'
});

App.AreaController = Ember.ObjectController.extend( Ember.AutoSaving, {
  bufferedFields: ['title', 'body'],
  instaSaveFields: ['postedAt', 'category'],
  titleLength: function() {
    return this.get('title').length;
  }.property('title')
});

// In your project route:
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this.controllerFor('areas').set('content', model.areas);
}
```

Now the areas controller will wrap each item in an AreaController proxy.

See [Ember ArrayController API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html)

Comment: Thanks Mike, but this will not work as I am not rendering the areas like that. Rather I am creating Polygons from the areas in the Google Maps API (in my view) and syncing back changes.

Comment: Ah ok. Editing my answer with an alternative that should work for that case.

Comment: Ah thanks Mike, that was very helpful. I still wish there was a way of specifying a "default" ObjectController that is used unless overridden.

Comment: I'll give the above a shot, but how would I expand this if I had a nested hasMany relationship? Say every area hasMany points - how would I handle that? Can I set the controller content of an ArrayController in my view?

Comment: I've not seen anyone attempt it without using the `{{each}}` helper and templates. That said i don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: I've been playing around with the second solution, but hit another roadblock. Namely, how do I access the controller of an area in the view? `area.get('controller')` returns `unknown` and something like `area.send('save')` gives me an error along the lines of `Error: Attempted to handle event 'delete' on <App.Area:ember1013:5230a2ee945f3b718a00006e> while in state root.loaded.saved.` Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: Can you open that as another SO question?

Comment: Done. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771141/access-item-controller-in-view).

Comment: Mike, any ideas? I'm still stuck on this.. :/