# Access item controller in view

Tags: ember.js

I have the following setup:

```
App.AreasController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'area'
});

// In my project route:
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this.controllerFor('areas').set('content', model.areas);
}
```

In my view I am now editing my `App.Areas`, and would like to invoke a controller method (of the itemController) for a given `area` from my view. How do I go about that?

If I try to access the controller `area.get('controller')` (where `area` represents one item from `model.areas`), it returns `unknown`.

If I do `area.send('save')`, I get an error along the lines of `Error: Attempted to handle event 'save' on <App.Area:ember1013:5230a2ee945f3b718a00006e> while in state root.loaded.saved.` Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want something like this:

```
{{#each}}
  <li {{action toggleEdit}}>
     <!-- Other stuff goes here -->
  </li>
{{/each}}

App.AreaController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing : false,
    toggleEdit : function(){
       this.set('isEditing', !this.get('isEditing'));
    }
});
```

Here's a JSBin of the general idea : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1045/edit

Inside of your view the "next level up" is the itemController, not the item itself.  You don't really need to try to get the controller from the item because the controller is sitting in between the view and the item.  So, you just call methods directly on the itemController.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not solve my problem. What is happening is that I am making the edits in the JS code of my view (which uses Google Maps). The problem is that in the JS of my view I do not seem to be able to access the itemController that I set up in setupController for some reason. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371129/itemcontroller-for-hasmany?lq=1) for my setup.

Comment: I guess I don't have the slightest idea about what you're really trying to do here... If you can put together a JSBis I'd be happy to take a look.